# Python type error: 'int' object is not iterable list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

When I try to run this code

```
check = [sum(board[r[0]] + board[r[1]] + board[r[2]]) for r in test]
    for row in check:
        if row == win:
            return True
```

I get a the error

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

However, when I run the following code, which does the same thing in a longer format, it runs smoothly and returns no errors

```
    for row in winConditions:
        checkA = board[row[0]]
        checkB = board[row[1]]
        checkC = board[row[2]]
        if checkA + checkB + checkC == int(win):
           return True
```

I am still gaining familiarity with list comprehensions, so I am unsure as to whether it is not possible, or is just some mistake that I have missed.

Comment: This isn't SQL, you don't need a `sum` function.

Comment: remove `sum(` and `)` and it should work. Also check your indentation in the code example; Proper indentation is **essential** when you're asking questions about Python on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `sum` on `board[r[0]] + board[r[1]] + board[r[2]]` (which is a number). `sum` expects a minimum of two numbers or one iterable as its parameters - since you're only passing one argument, it's expecting it to be iterable, hence that exception.